# How can I ensure that two foreign keys are equal?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have two tables:

```
script:
 - idScript (Primary Key)
 - idEnvironment (foreign key)

UAA:
 - idUser (Primary Key)
 - idEnvironment (Primary key)
 - idPaper (Primary Key)
```

So, I have a mxn relationship between then, getting this table:

```
UAAwithScript:
 - idUser (Primary Key)
 - idEnvironment (Primary Key)
 - idPaper (Primary Key)
 - idScript (Primary Key)
```

How can I ensure that `idEnvironment` is the same in Script and UAA? What is the best way to provide it?

Comment: Don't use more then one primary key per table.
Make a third table with idEnvironment as a primary key ( and a fourth with idPaper as primary key if needed ) and set idEnvironment as foreign key in both idUser and UAAwithScript.

Comment: This is unclear. What does "getting" a table mean? What do you mean by a column being the same in two tables? That the columns must contain exactly the same set of values? Or do you mean that in UAAwithScript should be the rows that are made from a script row and a UAA row that also have the same idEnvironment value? Please (Iike I just did) use enough words and effort and drafts to clearly refer to all your relevant things and parts of things and properties of things. A full example also helps (definitions, input, output, query, error messages). But don't let that let you skimp on words.